# How do I recreate this cream/neutral tone preset?

Tags: lightroom, photoshop, photo-editing, presets

How do I recreate this cream/neutral tone preset?

[image: Something like this]

Here are more pictures:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YR4er.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Mostly it is about color temperature, white balance (they're *not* the exact same thing), contrast, and then using an HSL/HSV/HSB (Hue-Saturation-Luminance/Value/Brightness) tool to mute some colors, shift the hues of other colors, and emphasize other colors.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly just using a luminosity mask and de-saturating the lighter parts:

[image]